# MongoDB aggregation projection on collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection full of documents like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5696db8a049c1bb2ecaaa10f"),
    "resultSets" : [
        {
            "headers" : [ "A", "B" ],
            "data" : [
                [ 0, 1 ]
            ]
        },

        {
            "headers" : [ "C", "D" ],
            "data" : [
                [ 2, 3 ]
            ]

        }
   ]
}
```

I would like to use aggregation to project this document as just.

```
{ C: 2, D: 3 }
```

Just wondering what the best way to do this would be.

Comment: Which MongoDB version are you using?

Comment: I'm using MongoDB Version 3.2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB 3.2 then **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)** would go a long way in getting the desired aggregation output especially dealing with [arrays](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-array/).

Run the following aggregation pipeline, which uses the **[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt)**  operator to return the desired values in the new keys:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$match": { "resultSets.headers": { "$in": [ "C", "D" ] } }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$resultSets" },
    {
        "$match": { "resultSets.headers": { "$in": [ "C", "D" ] } }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "C": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$resultSets.data", 0 ] },
            "D": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$resultSets.data", 1 ] }
        }
    }
]

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was super helpful. If I want to only match specific values in my array [C,D], is there another operator to use other than $in. For example, want to match documents where ONLY [C,D] exist in that specific order.

Comment: The reason is I have some arrays that are [C,D,E,F] and I want to only match arrays that are [C,D].